# Windows desktop search other than google desktop?

Tags: search

As a developer, i frequently need to perform complex searches for files. For example, search for file that starts with 'buf' and ends with '.c' or '.h' in a c:\sdk and c:\project\include. Windows search in vista+ is good, but for a lrage amount of sources it will search VERY long time if not index, and it's not possible to specify a number of folders to search in.

Is it any good and freeware tool available that allows to perform complex file search on windows platform? Google desktop requires indexing too and regexp support is very limited.

Comment: belongs on SuperUser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/Page.aspx?page=home) supports regex searches.

If you don't need to search file contents, [Voidtool's Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) is about the fastest thing I can find for NTFS (it uses the MFT).

Answer (score 2):

If you install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com), you can use `find` - which may make your life easier :)

Comment: find + grep = win. Cygwin is a must have for me on all Windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

[Launchy can do basic search on file names,](http://www.launchy.net/) and you can select which directories to include. Unfortunately the current version is not 100% stable for me, and the author seems to have more or less abandoned this great little app. It would be fantastic if others picked up development on Launchy.